# PoweSavingMode Vs App optimization

Tags: android, battery-saver

I need to know if there is any battery saving policy with the whole system or specific to my app.

I found out that you can check if the Power Saving Mode is activated or not by calling:

```
PowerManager oPowerManager = (PowerManager) oContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
boolean bActivated = oPowerManager.isPowerSaveMode();
```

But, how can I find out if my app is on the App optimization list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()` on `PowerManager`. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations%28java.lang.String%29):

> Return whether the given application package name is on the device's power whitelist. Apps can be placed on the whitelist through the settings UI invoked by ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS.

Comment: Thanks but it requieres Android release 23 (Marshmallow), but my Samsung S4 Lollipop already has that. How can I do same thing for Lollipop?

Comment: @Ton: Most likely, you don't. Samsung did their own thing, and unless their own Mobile SDK has an API for this, there's nothing in Android itself for it.